# Travel within Schengen country without RP

Tags: schengen, paperwork, permits

I'm from India and have applied for a Belgian Resident Permit. I received a Form 2, but have yet to receive the actual permit. Can I travel for a few days to some other Schengen county ?

Comment: What is Form 2? Is this a proof you have received residence permit but do not have your residence card yet?